# How to provide space between search icon to the search place holder in vue.js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

i developed a top navbar inside that it contains search bar ,i want to add search icon inside the search input box and i want to provide proper spacing between place holder and the icon  [[like this i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GonNN.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GonNN.png), i am trying so many ways but it's not working properly ,How to acheive this thing , please help me to fix this issue [[like this i am getting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlHU.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSlHU.png)
`Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img src="../assets/education.png" id="brand-logo" alt="notFound" />
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <p>Bookstore</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="input-group">
             <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control" placeholder='search...' />
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "colors";
.navbar-default {
    background: $redish_brown;
    height: 60px;
}
li p {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -1250px;
    width: 91px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal normal 18px/26px Roboto;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: $pale_white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 1;
}
img {
    background: transparent 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 31px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: 194px;
}
.input-group{
    margin-left:345px;
}
input[type="search"]{
    width: 490px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-top:-40px;
    background: #FCFCFC 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.fa-search{
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    // background: #9D9D9D 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: relative;
   padding-left:20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Inside `input[type="search"]` you can add `margin-left: 8px;`. You can of-course change the `8px` to suit your requirement.

Comment: @Chin.Udara, i need the space between search place holder to the icon ,not for the search box to the icon

Comment: Does it work when you add a `padding-left` to the input?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99, here padding-left used for providing space between search box to the BOOkStore <p> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do it this way:

```
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // to center the icon vertically
}

.input-group .fas {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.input-group input[type="search"] {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Flexbox be your friend. Would be also better if you start using flexboxes (or grids) to design your layout (rather than using negative margins to place each element). Here is a nice guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/